# ¿Como hacer funcionar esta funcion de cambio de Id?

Tags: javascript, funciones, function

tengo el siguiente problema. Necesito aplicar la siguiente forma de cambiar un id id.id = "idNuevo" en una función el problema es que no me funciona y yo creo que es porque no se como agregarle comillas al "idNuevo" sin que se vuelva un string

```
let imagen = document.getElementById("imag");
let imagen2 = document.getElementById("imag2")
let contadorClick = 0;

function cambioId(idACambiar = "", _idNuevo = "") {
    let a = idACambiar; 
    let b = _idNuevo;
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    a.id = b;
} 

  imagen.addEventListener("click", function cambiarImag() {
    contadorClick++;
    console.log(contadorClick);
    if(contadorClick>=4){
        contadorClick = 0;
    }
    if(contadorClick%2 != 0) {
        cambioId("imagen", "imagen2");
      }

    else {
        cambioId("imagen2", "imagen");
    }
})
```

Lo que quiero es que dentro de la función se realice el cambio de id de imagen a imagen2 al ser llamada la función en el primer if. La razón por la que quiero que se realice en la función es porque le quiero agregar un setTimeOut.
Espero haber sido lo más explícito posible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien necesitas hacer este cambio en tu código:

```
    if(contadorClick%2 != 0) {
        cambioId(this, "imagen2");
      }

    else {
        cambioId(this, "imagen");
    }
```

De esta forma, le pasas el objeto pulsado a la función, y entonces la asignación que haces con `a.id = b` funciona bien.

Y tambien debes realizar un cambio más. Cambia esto:

```
let imagen = document.getElementById("imag");
let imagen2 = document.getElementById("imag2")
```

por esto:

```
let imagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
let imagen2 = document.getElementById("imagen2")
```

aunque el `imagen2` no se usa para nada y tampoco tengo muy claro para que lo quieres allí, pues si existe como elemento en tu HTML estarás duplicando `id` cuando pulses sobre `imagen` y le cambie el **id**.

Te dejo un snippet de ejemplo para que veas como funciona (he tenido que inventarme el css y el html por que no está en la pregunta). Pulsa sobre la primera linea para que funcione:

```js
let imagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
let imagen2 = document.getElementById("imagen2")
let contadorClick = 0;

function cambioId(idACambiar = "", _idNuevo = "") {
  let a = idACambiar;
  let b = _idNuevo;
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  a.id = b;
}

imagen.addEventListener("click", function cambiarImag() {
  contadorClick++;
  console.log(contadorClick);
  if (contadorClick >= 4) {
    contadorClick = 0;
  }
  if (contadorClick % 2 != 0) {
    cambioId(this, "imagen2");
  } else {
    cambioId(this, "imagen");
  }
})
```

```css
#imagen {
  background-color: blue;
}
#imagen2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagen">
imagen
</div>
<div id="imagen2">
imagen2
</div>
```

Comment: No me estaría haciendo nada y ya hice el cambio. Si, el imag2 e imag son los id que están en css, pasa que no me copio el código cuando lo subí a la consulta. Lo que sucede es que quiero agregarle un intervalo de tiempo especifico solo al cambio de id y tengo otras modificaciones que hacer en el mismo if, es por eso que busco hacer el cambio de Id con una función y agregarle un setTimeOut.

Comment: Eso lo tendras que explicar mucho mejor porque creo que estas en un [problema XY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY) ahora mismo... ese mismo comentario te lo veo en todas tus preguntas y no sacas nada en claro en ninguna, y eso es porque no expones todo tu código ni tus intenciones reales y crees que arreglando Y se va a solucionar X, cuando seguramente lo que necesitas es otra cosa más global. ¿Porque no explicas bien lo que quieres en alguna pregunta completa con TODO el codigo en lugar de ir sacando las cosas poco a poco para luego complicarlas un poquito más a ver si asi chuta?

Comment: He agregado un snippet para que veas estos cambios en funcionamiento. Pulsa sobre `ejecutar` para verlo en acción, y luego pulsa sobre la primera linea para disparar el cambio de `id` las veces que quieras.

Comment: Perdón, trato de explayarme lo mejor posible pero soy confuso. Gracias ahí lo vi y me sirvió. Ahora estoy viendo como agregarle un setTimeOut porque de la forma que creí que funcionaría no me esta sirviendo. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Puedes cambiar el `id` de un elemento de la siguiente forma:

```
document.getElementById('idDelElemento').id = 'nuevoID';
```

Te dejo un ejemplo muy simple de un botón que cambia id

```js
let boton = document.getElementById("prueba");

  boton.addEventListener("click", function test() {
    boton.id = 'prueba1';
})
```

```html
<button id="prueba">Oprime aquí</button>
```

Comment: Lo que sucede es que quiero agregarle un intervalo de tiempo especifico solo al cambio de id y tengo otras modificaciones que hacer en el mismo if, es por eso que busco hacer el cambio de Id con una función y agregarle un setTimeOut